# Usability studies about B2B service pages?

Tags: usability, reports, b2b

I'm looking for research done on best practices when designing and writing content for B2B consulting service pages.

A B2B consulting firm could be management consulting firms, law firms or advertising agencies that have divided their offer into several services such as competitive audit, consumer research, etc.

I know that Norman Nielsen Group has made a [report on B2B website usability in general](https://www.nngroup.com/reports/b2b-websites-usability/) but I looking specifically for studies about making service pages useful and compelling.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning that service pages should be approached as any other page in other types of websites. Understand who your users are, what they are looking for, what questions they have. Answering these questions and providing clear, concise content (no marketing fluff) is most of it.

Also, consider your sales funnel and whether that matches how your users operate. What is the next step after reading the services? Contact a representative? checking out relevant case studies? Outside references?

Who is the person judging the service? How does your prospect choose vendors? What does that process look like? Is the user an executive position? or a lower position? What do they look for? What do they need and who do they talk to? How can you support that process?

This report, although a few years outdated, provides some suggestions into the type of content desired in B2B. Some of their findings can relate to service pages (page 21).

[B2B Web Usability Report](https://komarketing.com/files/b2b-web-usability-report-2015.pdf)

[image]